# When I am using meta tag css is not getting loaded

Tags: html, css

When I am using the meta tag  css is not getting loaded properly.

Here is my meta tag that I am using.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0"/>
```

I am using the above tag to disable the auto zooming of input fields in phones(iphone), but I have observed that, unfortunately when I am using above (meta)tag css is not getting loaded.

**EDIT**

Here is my html around meta tag

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "https://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="https://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/some_file.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/file2.css" />
```

Comment: Have you tried self closing the meta tag with "/>"?

Comment: Perhaps it would help if you were to add some context to this line – could you show the lines around it, including the line(s) where you include your CSS?

Comment: @ErmSo — The only thing that would help with would be Yellow Screen Of Death errors in XHTML. The complaint isn't a YSOD and it isn't XHTML.

Comment: @ErmSo  I am already using the self closing  tag.

Answer (score 0):

My problem got fixed with the modified version of meta tag
I am using the  following one

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no" />
```

Answer (score -1):

This my site header tag and its working for me:

```
<meta content='True' name='HandheldFriendly' />
<meta content='width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;' name='viewport' />
```